# My code produces junk while uncompressing

Tags: c++, zlib

I've written a simple program to test zlib `compress()` and `uncompress()` functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "zlib.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello!";
    size_t length = str.length();
    size_t newLength = compressBound(length);
    auto compressed = new char[newLength];
    if (compress((Bytef*)compressed, (uLongf*)&newLength, (const Bytef*)str.c_str(), length) != Z_OK)
    {
        throw runtime_error("Error while compressing data");
    }

    auto uncompressed = new char[length];
    if (uncompress((Bytef*)uncompressed, (uLongf*)&length, (Bytef*)compressed, newLength) != Z_OK)
    {
        throw runtime_error("Error while uncompressing data");
    }

    cout << uncompressed;

    delete[] compressed;
    delete[] uncompressed;
    return 0;
}
```

Why this program prints something like `Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello!¤¤¤¤&У3▒й!`? The junk at the end of the string differs from run to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto uncompressed = new char[length];`

Because this `uncompressed` array is NOT null terminated. Try the following code:

```
cout << std::string(uncompressed, length) << endl;
```

Comment: Or just go old-school, allocate `new char[length+1]` and set `uncompressed[length]='\0';`

Comment: @MSalters: But if you're going to rely on null-termination, that severely constraints your inputs. This answer is correct for C++ — you have the explicit length, so use it! :)